# How to add space from windows partition to ubuntu partition?

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu

I want to add partition size by stripping it from windows partition and adding it to ubuntu partition.

I am using Windows 8 and Ubuntu 12.10

So I have 100GB on windows and available is 30GB and
my Ubuntu has 15GB, how do I strip 20GB from windows and add it to my Ubuntu?

[image]

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What types of partitions (primary or logical) do you have and in what order are they? If possible, please post a screenshot from *Diskmgmt.msc* under Windows. Do you have an Ubuntu LiveCD?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by resizing volumes and changing the partition tables. I have done this in the past using the tool [gparted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/). It is available in most linux distributions.

You might have to run it from a live cd, if you want to resize an active partition.

Comment: So i have installed gparted on ubuntu. I could resize the windows partition while on ubuntu, but is it possible to merge the resized partition to ubuntu partition while im on ubuntu or have to be on live cd?

Comment: It depends. You can't resize a mounted partition, so you would have to unmount it first. IMO, it is a lot less hassle to use a life cd from the start. The ubuntu install-cd can be used as life cd.

Comment: I have shrinked 20gb from disk management on windows. so I have 20gb unallocated, my d drive and then my ubuntu partition 15gb, how do i use gparted to extend ubuntu partition with the unallocated space while the d drive is between the unallocated space and ubuntu partition?

Comment: Can't you simply slide the left side of your ubuntu partition to the left, to grab the empty space?

Comment: When I slide the ubuntu partition to the left it merged with the D drive. So what I did after was create another partition from C drive and installed ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

You can shrink your windows drive using the **Diskmgmt.msc** in Run dialog box and add free space to ubuntu using the live cd.